# Remoting actors without knowing about remote host address

Tags: java, akka

I want to build an actor system that has a common server at a static IP address and port. There will be many clients that know the server's address. The server doesn't know the IP addresses of the clients.

Configuration of the server:

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    transport = "akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport"
    netty {
      hostname = "46.38.232.161"
      port = 2552
    }
  }
}
```

Configuration of the client:

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = "akka.remote.RemoteActorRefProvider"
  }
  remote {
    transport = "akka.remote.netty.NettyRemoteTransport"
    netty {
      port = 2553
    }
  }
}
```

A client may come from the entire internet. Now I want to send messages from actors on the client to actors on the server. How does the server know, where to send back his messages? When I send `ActorPath`s to the server, so he would know the corresponding client's address, these don't contain the client's IP address.

Comment: Doesn't it work automatically? Location transparency and everything...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`akka.remote.netty.hostname` property may be set inside your `application.conf`, to a reachable IP address or resolvable name, in a case you want to communicate across the network. Actually your "client" nodes will also be a servers, when using Akka.

In a case if address is unknown at app start, consider this code fragment from Akka documentation:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

val customConf = ConfigFactory.parseString("""
  akka.actor.deployment {
    /my-service {
      router = round-robin
      nr-of-instances = 3
    }
  }
""")

// ConfigFactory.load sandwiches customConfig between default reference
// config and default overrides, and then resolves it.
val system = ActorSystem("MySystem", ConfigFactory.load(customConf))
```

Comment: This is the problem. I can't set `akka.remote.netty.hostname` explicitly in my `application.conf`, since the client address is not known before deployment.

Comment: I've edited the answer - you may create ActorSystem programmatically

Answer (score 1):

`Actor` has a method called `sender` that can be called in the actor's `receive` method to get a reference to the actor (`ActorRef`) that sent the current message. The `ActorRef` has an `ActorPath` which has a `RootActorPath` which has an `Address` which contains the host and port of the `ActorSystem` where the actor lives.